# In a very large spherical space station, could a contained core of densely packed extremely massive particles be used to create gravity?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, gravity, strange-matter

Assuming a future time with more advanced technological capabilities, could a densely packed core of something like strangelets or toplets, or just strange and top quarks singly, be used to create gravity? This would be for a very large spherical space station/city or a large moon or small planet with very low gravity. Low or zero G effects are usually countered through rotating stations or a technology that isn't explained. I'm looking for an at least theoretically plausible source of creating actual gravity.

Comment: Also, just for your reading pleasure, [this obligatory xkcd](https://what-if.xkcd.com/68/) might be relevant to your scenario.

Comment: Thanks MozerShmozer. I didn't realise I was asking a duplicate question. When I read through to find an answer I was only looking for references to quark matter, strangelets, toplets, etc., so I overlooked that gravity post.